# How to debug Joomla with php7

Tags: debug

Probably out of bad habit and laziness, before php 7, if I was debugging and   I wanted to know a value I would put in my code either

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($myvalue);
echo '</pre>';
```

or

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($myvalue);
echo '</pre>';
```

if the value I was after was in a function, for example, a function call after a form has been submitted I would use the same but with a break

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($myvalue);
echo '</pre>';
break;
```

or

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($myvalue);
echo '</pre>';
break;
```

Prior to php version 7, php would complain about the break but at least it would let me see the $myvalue. Now in php7 it just throws a fatal error.

So what is the correct way to debug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I often just use `die($variable);`, which should work in your case - `break` is just for loops.  NB I'm not saying this is the best way, and I'm interested to see if other users have better ways of debugging.

I'd also recommend you look at the [J!Dump plugin](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/j-dump) for what you are after.  This gives a lot more information when you dump something.

Comment: Doing a little research substituting break; with exit; works fine in php7.